# Selenium include mozilla instance

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, mozilla

I have a server on which I want to build a script to login to page which is using javascript. I want to use python selenium to achieve the same.

We have a shared drive which contains all the installed binaries and the same has to be included. So when running a python program I won't be using my #!/usr/bin/python instead efs/path../python, similarly all the packages are to be included in this ways. sys.path.append("/efs/path.../selenium-egg-info"). This works good, but as selenium would need firefox included, I could see mozilla in the path, but where are it's binary, exactly which folder to include inside mozilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think Selenium as launching 'firefox' behind the scenes. You won't see it but it's there and then accordingly opening up the webpage and manipulating things.

How do you think it does all that cool stuff without writing explicit url header etc. So for that you need to have a firefox installed with a physical display(monitor) installed.

You can fake a pyhsical terminal it's just input/output but you AFAIK you need to have a firefox installed. Sad news but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `firefox` executable since it comes with the `Selenium`

> Firefox driver is included in the selenium-server-stanalone.jar available in the downloads. The driver comes in the form of an xpi (firefox extension) which is added to the firefox profile when you start a new instance of FirefoxDriver.

See my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069774/how-webdriver-driver-new-firefoxdriver-works-internally/28069875#28069875)

Comment: But I see mentioned in many places, it needs firefox installed on the system. My unix box doesn't have firefox installed, neither I have permissions to install the same, also I get subprocess error, when I run my script.

Comment: of course it does. How would you run tests against a browser that doesn't exist? or am I missing something?

Comment: And, I guess we are talking about two different things here. You are talking about `FireFox` browser and I am talking about the `Firefox Driver`. Correct?

Comment: I don't have firefox installed and don't think that would be possible given I don't have root permissions. What I am thinking of is that including some firefox binary etc, it would work out.

Comment: I have no experience with that. Is there a standalone firefox? Don't even know if that's even possible